# Как выйти из цикла while? (2)

Tags: python

```
correct_password = 'QWERTY'
code_word = 'python'

attempt = 2
while True:
    if input() == correct_password:
        print('Введите кодовое слово')
        while attempt > 0:
            if input() == code_word:
                print('Двойная аутентификация прошла успешно')
                break
            attempt -= 1
    else:
        print('Пароль неправильный. Повторите попытку')
```

Comment: Задачку нужно решить только через вложенные циклы while

Comment: так при каком условии надо выйти? Распиши на бумажке последовательность. И забудь на время про ``while True``. Очевидно, что в while нужно добавить необходимое условие, а не просто тупо сделать бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Сделайте из данного кода какую-нибудь функцию и вместо break делайте return. Если так сделать нельзя, то создайте перед обоими циклами флажок (и установите его в False), который устанавливайте в True перед break а потом проверяйте во внешнем цикле и если он True, то делайте новый break

Comment: Условия задачи:

Если введенный пароль совпадает с correct_password, то программа пишет "Введите кодовое слово" и на это дает две попытки.  
Если за две попытки пользователь ввел слово, которое совпадает с code_word, то программа пишет "Двойная аутентификация прошла успешно" и заканчивает работать.
Если же пользователь дважды ошибся, то программа просто заканчивает работать.
Если введенный пароль не совпадает с correct_password, то программа пишет "Пароль неправильный. Повторите попытку"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу получилось разобраться, добавил флаг, немного изменил код и нашел ответ

```
correct_password = 'QWERTY'
code_word = 'python'

authenticated = False
while not authenticated:
    attempt = 2
    if input() == correct_password:
        print('Введите кодовое слово')
        while attempt > 0:
            attempt -= 1
            if input() == code_word:
                print('Двойная аутентификация прошла успешно')
                authenticated = True
                break
            elif attempt == 0:
                authenticated =True
    else:
        print('Пароль неправильный. Повторите попытку')
```

Comment: Проход аутентификации даже когда ввели кодовое слово неверно все три раза!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал что-то вроде такого:

```py
correct_password = 'QWERTY'
code_word = 'python'

attempt = 2
authenticated = False
while not authenticated:
    attempt = 2 # <-- в случае, если пользователь потратил две попытки, 
    # то при введении нового пароля нужно дать еще две попытки
    if input() == correct_password:
        print('Введите кодовое слово')
        while attempt > 0:
            if input() == code_word:
                print('Двойная аутентификация прошла успешно')
                authenticated = True # если код введен правильно, то устанавливаем флаг в истину, 
                # это позволит завершиться внешнему циклу while
                break
            attempt -= 1
        else:
            print("Ошибка аутентификации") # добавил сообщение о превышении числа попыток
    else:
        print('Пароль неправильный. Повторите попытку')
```